# Integration Technique Strategy

Tags: integration

There are many types of integration techniques. Are there any good ways to figure out which one to use or is that just a developed intuition that comes with experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mainly there are three techniques

1) Integration by substituion

Here you take a small expression of x from whole equation that is goin to be integrated and put that equal to a new variable. By this you make the integral in terms of a new variable and much simpler to integrate.

2)Integration by parts

It is integration technique like product rule of diffrentiation.

3)Integration by trigonometric substituion

It is same as Integration by substituion except for that in this x becomes any trigonometric expression (sin,cos, and tan) and we have to take care of the range of x.

Trigonometric substituion is simple to indentify whereas Integration by substituion and Integration by parts are  difficult to indentify.So for Integration by substituion and by parts, you have to practice a so that you are able to identify which technique to use in first glance.